# Unable to get each item from selected multiple line Jlist?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel, listcellrenderer

After doing lots of research i am still unable to get items from selected multiple line jlist. Here is my code for listSelectionListener:

```
list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            ListModel model = list.getModel();

            for(int i=0; i < model.getSize(); i++){
                System.out.println( model.getElementAt(i));  
            }
        }
    });
```

I also added a button to print the selected items:

```
btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            ListModel model = list.getModel();

            for(int i=0; i < model.getSize(); i++){
                System.out.println( model.getElementAt(i));  
            }
        }
    });
```

but Still getting the same output :

```
com.example.main.Student@c36b5fb
com.example.main.Student@2e61eb2
com.example.main.Student@151f708e
com.example.main.Student@563e55b0
```

I am expecting output "Name: Paul0 Age: 0." I also tried adding DefaultlistModel instead of ListModel but the output is same. Please help I want each item inside selected line.I am using JDK8. Below is complete working code.

```
    import java.awt.Component;

    import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
    import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JList;
    import javax.swing.ListModel;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import javax.swing.JButton;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;

    import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
    import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;


public class Test3 {  

JList<Student> list;
DefaultListModel model;

public Test3() {
    list = new JList();
    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            ListModel model = list.getModel();

            for(int i=0; i < model.getSize(); i++){
                System.out.println( model.getElementAt(i));  
            }
        }
    });
    model = new DefaultListModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        model.addElement(new Student("Paul" + i, i));
    }
    list.setModel(model);
    list.setCellRenderer(new MyListCellRenderer());

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(list);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Print");
    btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            ListModel model = list.getModel();

            for(int i=0; i < model.getSize(); i++){
                System.out.println( model.getElementAt(i));  
            }
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Test3();
        }
    });
}

private class MyListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list, Object value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        Student label = (Student) value;
        String name = label.getName();
        int age = label.getAge();
        String labelText = "<html>Name: " + name + "<br/>Age: " + age;
        setText(labelText);

        return this;
    }

   }
}

class Student {
    String name;
    int age;
    public Student(String name, int age) {
       this.name = name;
       this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getAge() { return age; }
}
```

Comment: Your `Student` class doesn't override the `toSring` method, so it's printing the default result of `toString`, which is your output.  This means, you code works, congradulations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementAt` is returning the `Object` at the specified position, which happens to be a `Student` in your case.  `System.out.println` is using the object's `toString` method to print the object, so, based on your code, it seems to be working.

But, if you want the output of `"Name: Paul0 Age: 0."`, you need to change the `Student` class and override the `toString` method to meet your requirements

```
class Student {
    String name;
    int age;
    public Student(String name, int age) {
       this.name = name;
       this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getAge() { return age; }
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + getName() + " Age: " + getAge());
    }
}
```

Or something like that

You might also want to take a look at [`JList#getSelectedValuesList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValuesList()) to get a `List` of the items that the user has selected (but I might be misinterrupting your question)

You could also have a look at [Object as a Superclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html) (look for the section called "The toString() Method") for more details